# How can I hide an HTML table row <tr> in aspx file and enable in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very small search functionality and I have a table row called "Search Results", I want this table row get displayed whenever i have something to display from the search results. So I want to hide this row by default and enable via code behind when my search is fetching some result.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr id="srchResultHeader" style="display: none;" class="header">
            <td colspan="2" class="tdlogintitle" visible="false">Search Results</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>/*Data to display actual result from database*/</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get the reference of the above table id "srchResultHeader" in my code behind? What is wrong here in my code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An `id` by itself is just a client-side identifier.  In order for this to be referenced as a server-side object it needs to be a server-side control.  The easiest way would just be to add `runat="server"` on the existing element:

```
<tr runat="server" id="srchResultHeader" style="display: none;" class="header" >
```

In this case you probably don't even need the `style` attribute, since you're controlling the hide/show functionality in server-side code.  You can just set `.Visible` on the control to determine whether or not it renders to the client-side markup at all.

Answer (score 4):

You could use server-side `<asp:Table>` for this very purpose. Otherwise `<tr>` is a client-side thing and is not directly accessible in the server-side code. `<asp:Table>` will render `<table>` tag on the client-side, but you can access it in the code-behind through its `ID`. The structure looks like this:

```
<asp:Table ID="MyTable" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow runat="server" ID="MyRow1">
        <asp:TableCell>Some value</asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

You can now write something like this in the code-behind:

```
MyRow1.Visible = False;
```

Answer (score 3):

### .aspx

```
  <tr id="divDriverName1"  runat="server" >
<td >  
<label class=" ">label1 </label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class=" form-control"></asp:TextBox>  
</td>  
</tr>
```

### .aspx.cs

```
           ContentPlaceHolder myPlaceHolder = (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); 
         HtmlTableRow ct = (myPlaceHolder.FindControl("divDriverName1")) as HtmlTableRow;
             divDriverName1.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none");
```

Comment: Thanks fro your Solution but you don't use "ct"  HtmlTableRow in

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row" id="divhiddenInfo2" runat="server" style="display: none">
</div>
```